# SQL Server 2008 Insert non-duplicates from count query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert records from an old table to a new version of the same table. The problem is that the old table was made about 16 years ago by a self taught database guy who obviously skipped over foreign keys (so every table has an autonumber primary key and there are no integrity constraints). I wish to take all the records and insert them into my table, which the table has the following key:

```
(ProjectID, SubProjectID, PhaseID, SubPhaseID, DisciplineID)
```

I did a quick query to group on and count the above key in the old table and I get 480 records with essentially what would be a non-unique key in my new table.

My question: Is it possible to make a query that takes all the rows that did not turn up in my count query and insert them into the new table? as my count query is grouping on 5 fields and I wish to insert the full records of 17 fields.

My attempt so far returns 0 records entered so I hope am close. 
Also I couldn't find anything on this already on SO so apologies if this is a duplicate

```
INSERT INTO [ERP].[dbo].[Fees]
           ([ProjectID]
           ,[SubProjectID]
           ,[PhaseID]
           ,[SubPhaseID]
           ,[DisciplineID]
           ,[DatePhaseCommenced]
           ,[TotalFee]
           ,[EnggFee]
           ,[DraftFee]
           ,[ProposalDate]
           ,[Comment]
           ,[AuthDate]
           ,[AuthDescription]
           ,[HourlyRate]
           ,[Closed]
           ,[ClosedDate]
           ,[SubmissionDate])
     SELECT 
         F.ProjectNo, 1, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID, '1/1/2000', 
         F.Amount, F.Engineering, F.Drafting, F.[Proposal Date],
         F.Comment, F.AuthDate, F.AuthDescription, F.HourlyRate, 
         CASE 
             WHEN F.DontBookTime = 1 THEN 1 
             WHEN F.DontBookTime_Date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
         END, 
         F.DontBookTime_Date, F.SubmissionDate 
     FROM 
         Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
     WHERE 
         NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                         F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
                     FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
                     WHERE (F.Amount > 0 OR F.Engineering > 0 OR F.Drafting > 0) 
                     GROUP BY 
                         F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
                      HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
GO
```

UPDATE::

I realised I can do an insert on just the primary key where not existing in my query and then update from the original with the appropriate values. Having a slight problem with that query as well.

Select duplicates query:

```
SELECT F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
GROUP BY F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)
```

Then select all not in the duplicates query :

```
SELECT F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
                      F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID  
                  FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
                  GROUP BY 
                      F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
                  HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
```

But still returning no values...

Comment: `WHEN F.DontBookTime_Date <> NULL` will **always** be false - you cannot use the normal equality and inequality operators with `NULL` - you can **only** check `IS NULL` or `IS NOT NULL` against a potential `NULL` value ...

Comment: Ah yes, I keep making that mistake in SQL. I fixed that but it is still resulting in 0 rows with that big insert query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You made a mistake in `WHERE` clause
Your condition

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT ...)
```

can be only true or false (depends on returns any records your `SELECT ...` or not), but you try to filter your records with boolean clause.

Second, `WHERE NOT EXISTS .. HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1)` is the same as `HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1)`, am I right?

Third, use `JOIN` tables instead of using `WHERE NOT EXISTS`

```
    SELECT 
             F.ProjectNo, 1, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID, '1/1/2000', 
             F.Amount, F.Engineering, F.Drafting, F.[Proposal Date],
             F.Comment, F.AuthDate, F.AuthDescription, F.HourlyRate, 
             CASE 
                 WHEN F.DontBookTime = 1 THEN 1 
                 WHEN F.DontBookTime_Date IS NOT NULL THEN 1 
                 ELSE 0 
             END, 
             F.DontBookTime_Date, F.SubmissionDate 
         FROM 
             Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
         JOIN 
             (SELECT    F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
                         FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
                         WHERE (F.Amount > 0 OR F.Engineering > 0 OR F.Drafting > 0) 
                         GROUP BY 
                             F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
                          HAVING (COUNT(*) = 1)) as Count_F 
         ON F.ProjectNo = Count_F.ProjectNo and F.PhaseID = Count_F.PhaseID 
        and F.SubPhase = Count_F.SubPhase and F.DisciplineID = Count_F.DisciplineID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to cross-check: Replace '' with -1 for integers

```
SELECT F.ProjectNo, F.PhaseID, F.SubPhase, F.DisciplineID 
FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees F 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM Multitech.dbo.Fees X
where 
Isnull( F.ProjectNo,'') =  Isnull( X.ProjectNo,'') and  
Isnull( F.PhaseID,'') = Isnull( X.PhaseID,'')  and  
Isnull( F.SubPhase,'') = Isnull( X.SubPhase,'') and  
Isnull( F.DisciplineID ,'') = Isnull( X.DisciplineID ,'') 
GROUP BY 
 X.ProjectNo, X.PhaseID, X.SubPhase, X.DisciplineID 
 HAVING (COUNT(*) > 1))
```